# Insert several images at once using macro scripting in LibreOffice

Tags: python, macros, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I am writing a macro for LibreOffice Writer in Python.
I need to insert several images in one document, one after another with minimal space inbetween them.

The folowing code inserts all the images in the same area and all of them are overlapped.

I need to advance the cursor below the inserted image everytime a new image is inserted.
I have tried the cursor.gotoEnd(), cursor.goDown() and other such methods but none seem to work.

How do I make this work?

```
def InsertAll():
    desktop = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDesktop()
    doc=desktop.loadComponentFromURL('private:factory/swriter','_blank',0,())

    text = doc.getText()
    cursor = text.createTextCursor()

    file_list = glob.glob('/path/of/your/dir/*.png')
    for f in file_list:
        img = doc.createInstance('com.sun.star.text.TextGraphicObject') 
        img.GraphicURL = 'file://' + f
        text.insertTextContent(cursor, img, False)
        cursor.gotoEnd(False) <- doesnt advance the cursor downwards

    return None
```

Comment: Just from inserting pictures manually, my experience is that you have to add newlines after the picture before there is a place for the cursor to go.  So adding a newline or two to the document in between picture inserts may be something to try.

Comment: I tried that too. Didn't work.

Comment: There is a document by Andrew Pitonyak available as the download "English macro document" from his OpenOffice site [http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php).  In the example of inserting multiple images, the code looks for a text character and inserts and image after each instance of the character.  (The code example is in StarBasic, but the API names are the same so it shouldn't be too bad to apply it to Python.)  Perhaps you could imitate this and, before inserting the images, insert (size of file_list) text characters each followed by a newline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a paragraph break after each image:

`from com.sun.star.text.ControlCharacter import PARAGRAPH_BREAK`

```
    text.insertTextContent(cursor, img, False)
    text.insertControlCharacter(cursor, PARAGRAPH_BREAK, False)
    cursor.gotoEnd(False)
```

This will separate the images... by a paragraph

Andrew's book is a basic source for solving many OpenOffice scripting problems: +1