# libreoffice python: how to set text wrap properties of images

Tags: python, libreoffice, watermark

From stackoverflow I learned how to set image properties in LibreOffice Writer with pyhton macros, via com.sun.star.text.WrapTextMode. Now I use that to set the text wrap to THOUGHT. Now I would like to set the image to background, like a watermark.

In LibreOffice Writer interactively I select an image, right-click on it and the context menu contains the "Wrap" commands, one is "Wrap Through" and the other one is "In Background".

In the python macro I have the following code (from [Insert several images at once using macro scripting in LibreOffice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449712/insert-several-images-at-once-using-macro-scripting-in-libreoffice) and from the often quoted Andrew Pitonyak):

```
from com.sun.star.text.WrapTextMode import THROUGHT
```

and then to insert the image:

```
img = doc.createInstance('com.sun.star.text.TextGraphicObject') 
element_url = 'file://' + file_name
img.GraphicURL = element_url
img.Surround = THROUGHT
text.insertTextContent(cursor, img, False)
```

So what is the code to put it "In Background"?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow!  Please edit your question to provide the following information: How did you do it interactively?  That will make it more clear what you are asking.  Also please post the important lines of the code that sets the wrap mode, and/or a link to the stackoverflow example you used.  Are you using LibreOffice Writer or perhaps Impress?

Comment: Hello Jim K. Is the question now clear enough?

Comment: Yes, it is better now.

Answer (score 1):

[MRI](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/mri-uno-object-inspection-tool) shows that setting "In Background" causes the [Opaque](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/BaseFrameProperties.html#Opaque) attribute to be false.  So add this to the code:

```
img.Opaque = False
```

By the way, [Surround](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/BaseFrameProperties.html#Surround) is deprecated.  Try setting [TextWrap](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/TextContent.html#TextWrap) to `THROUGHT` instead.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. That is the solution. Especially the hint to MRI is useful, as I did not know that before.

Comment: Glad to know it helped.  Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).